# How to shuffle elements in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, append, shuffle

I have this dataframe.

```
    Name    A   B   C   D   E
0   John    1   2   3   2   3
```

And I want this result.

```
    Name    A   B   C   D   E
0   John    1   3   2   3   2 
1   John    3   2   1   2   3 
2   John    2   1   3   2   3 
...
49  John    1   2   2   3   3 
50  John    2   1   3   2   3
```

I have hundreds of columns like cols A,B,C,...

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: How is the dataframe supposed to look?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import pandas lib and convert it into pandas dataframe. For that you can do this>>>

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['Column_A','Column_B','Column_C'])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there are simplier ways, but one way to do it is this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':list(x[0][0]), 'b':list(x[1][0]),'c': list(x[2][0])}, index=range(len(x[0][0])))

>>> print(df)
      a    b    c
0   0.0  0.0  0.0
1   1.0  1.0  1.0
2   3.0  3.0  3.0
3   0.0  0.0  0.0
4   1.0  1.0  1.0
..  ...  ...  ...
88  0.0  0.0  0.0
89  1.0  1.0  1.0
90  0.0  0.0  0.0
91  0.0  0.0  0.0
92  0.0  0.0  0.0
```